# What is the best way to store data while redirecting to and from an external URL?

Tags: angular

I am generating a random string which is included in a redirect URL to Reddit's API. I am supposed to check the string when I redirect back to my Angular application for security purposes. See below for how I am generating the string:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { RandomService } from '../random.service';

@Injectable()
export class SavedPostsService {

private _state: string;
public get state(): string {
        return this._state;
    }

public constructor(private _randomService: RandomService) {
        this._state = this._randomService.generateStateString(20);
    }

public getRedditAuthorizationUrl(): string {
    reurn `https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/authorize?client_id=upw3i_YafZpoXw&response_type=code` +
        `&state=${this.__state}` +
        `&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/saved-posts&duration=temporary&scope=history`;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I am getting a new instance of my RandomService after I redirect back to my application, so the string is getting re-generated and therefore not matching when I check.

**My two main questions are:
1) Is it expected that the service would be instantiated again after redirecting back to my application?
2) How can I store information in an Angular 2 application while redirecting to and from an external URL?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When redirecting back to your application, everything will be reinstantiated.  One solution is to store the string in localStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem('someName', someValue);

localStorage.getItem('someName');
```

You might want to create some sort of logic to clear the item out of localStorage when no longer needed and generate a new string.  You service could then check at start up if a string exists in localStorage, if so then use it, if not then generate a new one.

Comment: This has gotten me around my conundrum. Thanks!